# Algebraic proof that pmf of hypergeometric distribution sums to 1

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to see an algebraic proof that the probability mass function of the hypergeometric distribution sums to 1. I know how to prove it combinatorially.

**My attempt:**

Given: $P(X=x) = \frac{\binom{M}{x} \binom{N-M}{K-x}}{N \choose K}, 0 \leq x \leq K$

I basically need to prove what's below:

$N \choose K$ = $M \choose 0$$N-M\choose K$ + $M \choose 1$$N-M\choose K-1$ $ + \ldots +$ 
$M \choose K$$N-M\choose 0$

**The only problem is that I assume the conclusion when proving the hypothesis! This is flawed. For instance, I am assuming that the sum equals 1 in order to prove that it equals 1.**

Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often, you use

$$\binom{x}{y} = \binom{x-1}{y} + \binom{x-1}{y-1}$$

for these sorts of things. Eyeballing it, it looks like you just start with $\binom{N}{K}$ and repeat this until you have your equation.

---

Alternatively, when you know the equation to prove, induction often works quite easily for these. The hard part is usually finding the equation.

Comment: Or, use [Vandermonde's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity).